# Performance loss from extensive use of shared_ptr as if C++ being garbage-collected?

Tags: c++, performance, shared-ptr

I was wondering about the performance issues of the reference counted `shared_ptr`s, and so I wrote a dumb program which computes `pow(2, n)` in a very inefficient way with millions of memory allocations and deallocations, in order to test `shared_ptr`s while not making the compiler optimize everything away, even with full optimization.

Compiled with,

```
g++ t.cpp -std=c++11 -ot -DV_ -pedantic -Ofast -s -fwhole-program
```

where -DV_ means to use `std::vector` as the container.

Ran as,

```
valgrind ./t 10000
```

which means to compute `pow(2, 10000)` shows me,

```
total heap usage: 45,174,051 allocs, 45,174,051 frees, 783,160,061 bytes allocated
```

and

```
time ./t 10000
```

outputs

```
real    0m1.698s
user    0m1.693s
sys     0m0.004s
```

which IS surprisingly fast, considering the amount of heap allocation done. The system is a laptop with an i5 CPU and an Ubuntu Linux OS.

The basic pattern I used here is defining container classes extending the `shared_ptr` to its original class.

```
#if defined(V_)
    #define C_ std::vector
#elif defined(L_)
    #define C_ std::list
#elif defined(D_)
    #define C_ std::deque
#else
    #error
#endif

template<typename T>
class Container : public std::shared_ptr<C_<T>>
{
public:
    Container():
        std::shared_ptr<C_<T>>(new C_<T>)
    {
    }
};

class String : public std::shared_ptr<std::string>
{
public:
    String():
        std::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string)
    {
    }
    String(const char* s):
        std::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string(s))
    {
    }
    const char* getCString()
    {
        return get()->c_str();
    }
};
```

This way I do not have to worry at all whether to pass by value or by reference, const reference, rvalue reference et cetera. Passing everything by value works fine and is very cheap. It should just be a pointer copy and a reference count update. I can add a few deep copy methods as needed,  by which I can also easily see where exactly a deep copy is happening in my program. Letting a whole vector being value copied just because of a missed reference mark will not happen. I'd also say situations where deep copies of large objects are necessary is not common.

Well, the benefits are obvious. In other words, either Java or C# will offer much better productivity than C++. But there must be performance loss. In most user applications this loss can be literally nothing, but I like writing games, which must finish computing every frame in 30ms or so. I really can't write games with real garbage collected languages, Java for example, because I do see the game pausing unexpectedly for a very short but noticeable moment and restoring back. It just feels not right. But with reference counted (pseudo-)garbage collection, the point where the resources are claimed or released is quite much guaranteed.

So I am thinking about to start a project that use this pattern from the very base, but I don't have much experience in using reference counted pointers for big-enough projects. I am really in the experimenting phase. But would you say using `shared_ptr`s in time critical programs is basically not a good idea, and no one knows what its impact will be after the project gets big enough, up to the point it is nearly impossible to change anything so deep inside and used everywhere. (I am actually worried about this part). Or am I simply overly undervaluing the greatness of modern computing machines?

Do you have any good or bad experience dealing with smart pointers? Will these work fine with multiple threads? How much can the compiler do optimizations on them? Do modern hardware deal with reference counting operations well? Any other helpful facts about reference counted pointers?

Below you can see the whole test program, if you're interested.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

#if defined(V_)
    #define C_ std::vector
#elif defined(L_)
    #define C_ std::list
#elif defined(D_)
    #define C_ std::deque
#else
    #error
#endif

void check(bool isOkay)
{
    if (!isOkay)
    {
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

template<typename T>
class Container : public std::shared_ptr<C_<T>>
{
public:
    Container():
        std::shared_ptr<C_<T>>(new C_<T>)
    {
    }
};

class String : public std::shared_ptr<std::string>
{
public:
    String():
        std::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string)
    {
    }
    String(const char* s):
        std::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string(s))
    {
    }
    const char* getCString() const
    {
        return get()->c_str();
    }
};

class SlowInteger : public Container<int>
{
public:
    SlowInteger()
    {
    }
    SlowInteger(int n)
    {
        check(0 <= n && n < 20);
        if (n < 10)
        {
            get()->push_back(n);
        }
        else
        {
            get()->push_back(n - 10);
            get()->push_back(1);
        }
    }
    int toInt() const
    {
        if (get()->size() == 1)
        {
            return get()->front();
        }
        else
        {
            return get()->front() + 10 * get()->back();
        }
    }
};

class VerySlowInteger : public Container<SlowInteger>
{
public:
    VerySlowInteger(String stringNumber)
    {
        for (auto it = stringNumber->rbegin(); it != stringNumber->rend(); ++it)
        {
            get()->push_back(SlowInteger(*it - '0'));
        }
    }
    void x2()
    {
        int m = 0;
        for (auto it = get()->begin(); it != get()->end(); ++it)
        {
            int n = it->toInt() * 2;
            if (n < 10)
            {
                *it = SlowInteger(m + n);
                m = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                *it = SlowInteger(n - 10 + m);
                m = 1;
            }
        }
        if (m == 1)
        {
            get()->push_back(SlowInteger(1));
        }
    }
    void x2n(int n)
    {
        check(n > 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            x2();
        }
    }
    String toString()
    {
        String s;
        for (auto it = get()->rbegin(); it != get()->rend(); ++it)
        {
            s->push_back(it->toInt() + '0');
        }
        return s;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    check(argc == 2);
    int n = std::atoi(argv[1]);
    check(n > 0);
    VerySlowInteger nSlow("1");
    nSlow.x2n(n);
    String s = nSlow.toString();
    std::cout << s.getCString() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Note that shared_ptr is not intended to be inherited from, at least not public inheritance and polymorphic behavior. One way of seeing that is the lack of virtual functions and virtual destructor.

Comment: I think thinking of "garbage collection" is fundamentally misleading. As Eric Raymond [put it nicely](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx), garbage collection simulates infinite memory. C++ does not have garbage collection, and it does not produce garbage; rather, it produces ownership and responsibility. The purpose of a shared pointer is to express shared ownership. Use a shared pointer when and if you need to share ownership.

Comment: "either Java or C# will offer much better productivity than C++." - you're asking basic questions about shared pointers and *telling us* C++ is less productive than those languages *at the same time*?

Comment: @KerrekSB you mean Raymond Chen no?

Comment: @EdChum: I do, sorry :-) (I initially thought the article was by Eric Lippert and then my brain performed undefined behaviour.)

Comment: So you're complaining about performance in a convoluted example that does millions of unnecessary allocations with no optimization?  Just think about that for a second.

Comment: I think you will see a surprising performance improvement if you don't copy the shared_ptr so much. This operation is not as cheap as you may think.

Comment: @Alan No. (fifteen-chars)